# Drush not recognizing drupal root folder

Tags: drupal, windows-8, mamp, drush

This one is driving me crazy.

Whenever i use "drush dl" to download site_audit or drupalgeddon it downloads these modules inside the drush home folder ( /users/[user]/.drush ) instead of the current sites modules folder.

the "drush status" and the "drush @site-alias status" command gives me the correct site information, see below:

C:\wamp\www\drupal>drush dl site_audit
Install location C:\Users\Thomas/.drush/site_audit already exists. Do you want
 to overwrite it? (y/n): n
Skip installation of site_audit to                                   [warning]

C:\wamp\www>drush @drupal status

Drupal version         :  7.34
 Site URI               :  localhost/drupal
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database username      :  root
 Database name          :  drupal
 Default theme          :  garland
 Administration theme   :  garland
 PHP executable         :  php.exe
 PHP configuration      :   C:\Users\Thomas.drush\php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush version          :  6.0
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :  C:\Users\Thomas/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
 Drupal root            :  /mamp/htdocs/drupal
 Site path              :  sites/default
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files

Also, when i try to download a module that already exist in the current sites modules folder it tells me so correctly. Same goes for the "en" command. I can also disable or uninstall modules successfully. Uninstalling does not remove the folder, tough.

The only thing i have noticed is that "drush configuration" does not show a path. However, i did copy the example file inside the .drush home folder AND one inside the sites/all/drush folder (i removed the 'example' from the filename off course).

Running windows 8 and tried both MAMP and WAMP with same results. I really hope someone can help me with this cause i am pulling my hair here.

---

Update: 
I tested the dl command with other modules and they are downloaded to the correct folder. I cleared the drush cache several times. Yet site_audit and drupalgeddon keep getting downloaded to the wrong folder. I just don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. These are both not modules but Drush extensions, hence the alternative download locations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem is, that you didn't specify the site-alias in your "drush dl" statement.

You run

```
drush @site-alias status
```

containing the site-alias, but

```
drush dl site_audit
```

without a sie-alias. I suppose you are in the drush folder, as drush downloads to the current folder, if no root folder is given explicitly or via site-alias.